# How to run Akka Streams graph on a separate dispatcher with timeout?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

This question is based on a pet project that I did and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641861/akka-http-blocking-in-a-future-blocks-the-server/34645097) thread. Inside a Akka HTTP route definition, I start a long-running process, and naturally I want to do that without blocking the user. I'm able to achieve this with the code snippet below:

```
blocking-io-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 16
  }
  throughput = 1
}
```

---

```
complete {
  Try(new URL(url)) match {
    case scala.util.Success(u) => {
      val src = Source.fromIterator(() => parseMovies(u).iterator)

      src
        .via(findMovieByTitleAndYear)
        .via(persistMovies)
        .toMat(Sink.fold(Future(0))((acc, elem) => Applicative[Future].map2(acc, elem)(_ + _)))(Keep.right)
        // run the whole graph on a separate dispatcher
        .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.dispatcher("blocking-io-dispatcher"))
        .run.flatten
        .onComplete {
          _ match {
            case scala.util.Success(n) => logger.info(s"Created $n movies")
            case Failure(t) => logger.error(t, "Failed to process movies")
          }
        }

      Accepted
    }
    case Failure(t) => logger.error(t, "Bad URL"); BadRequest -> "Bad URL"
  }
}
```

What's the problem then if I've already solved it? The problem is that I'm not sure how to set a timeout. The execution of the graph creates a `Future` that executes until complete on the dedicated `blocking-io-dispatcher`. If I add a `Await` call, the code blocks. Is there a way to put a timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`completionTimeout` stage should help here. Example below:

```
src
    .completionTimeout(5.seconds)
    ...
    .run.flatten
    .onComplete {
        case scala.util.Success(n) => logger.info(s"Created $n movies")
        case Failure(t: TimeoutException) => logger.error(t, "Timed out")
        case Failure(t) => logger.error(t, "Failed to process movies")
    }
```

Docs reference [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#completionTimeout).

Comment: Thanks you; but your code doesn't compile as shown. `completionTimeout` has to be applied before attempting to materialize the graph (`toMat`). I've accepted your answer as is almost correct.